# Copy values from one array to another, if condition satisfied

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a matrix, that can vary in size. But for now, let's say it's a 6X6 matrix. It contains values on all the indexes, and some of these values can be 0.

Say the matrix looks like this:

```
var half_MW = [
    [0,1,1,0,0,0],
    [1,0,1,0,0,0],
    [1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,1],
    [0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,1,1,0]]
```

Now I want to create another array (lets call it `data`), and copy only the values from `half_MW` that don't have 0 (i.e  (0,0) = 0, but also (0,3) = 0 etc.

What I'm not sure about, is how to create the array that I call `data`.

Here is my attempt

```
  var half_MW = ... (values shown above)
  var data = [];

  for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    var dataCols = [];
    for(j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
      if(half_MW[i][j] != 0) {
        dataCols[i] = half_MW[i];
        dataCols[j] = half_MW[j];
      }     
    }

    data[i] = dataCols;
```

The result I get, is that the data/values are copied, but some indexes contain 0, which is what I don't want. So actually, `data` array, should not be a 6x6 array, it should be smaller, since those indexes from the `half_MW` array that contain 0 should be left out.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: So you want to filter out the ``0``s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code do not work because you are missing `dataCols.push(half_MW[i][j]);` in the inner loop. Change that and it works:

```js
var half_MW = [
    [0,1,1,0,0,0],
    [1,0,1,0,0,0],
    [1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,1],
    [0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,1,1,0]];
var data = [];

for(i = 0; i < half_MW.length; ++i) {
  var dataCols = [];
  for(j = 0; j < half_MW[0].length; ++j) {
    if(half_MW[i][j] != 0) {
      dataCols.push(half_MW[i][j]);
    }     
  }
  data[i] = dataCols;
}
console.log(data);
```

You can also make the loop condition more dynamic by using `half_MW.length` for outer loop and `half_MW[0].length` for inner loop.

Comment: @Rajesh OP has also not mentioned that the inner array should be of same length so the concern was to get the error out of the code from the OP's code

Answer (score 2):

You could map the filtering with `Boolean` as callback.

```js
var half_MW = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]],
    result = half_MW
        .map(a => a.filter(Boolean))
        .filter(a => a.length);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Not sure but, per OP's statement *copy only the values from...* probably, `.filter(x => x.filter(Boolean))` would suit better.

Comment: No no. I meant `half_MW.filter(a => a.filter(Boolean).length > 0);`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `map` to loop al the arrays and return them after you `filter` the condition out.

I this case it looks like you want to remove all the `0`s if not pliss comment so I can edit

Hope this helps :>

```js
var half_MW = [[0,1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,1,0]];

var data = half_MW.map(m=>{
  return m.filter(c=> c!=0)
})

console.log(data)
```